# How to change toolbar color according to the radio button selected after the second login using android kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin, sharedpreferences

I need to change the `toolbar` color in the second login time according to the `RadioButton` `selected` in the first login time in android kotlin. I've used `sharedPreferences` to get the value of the `radioButton` selected in the first login.

To set the radio button value in `sharedPreferences` at the first login time, I've used the following code

```
fun setSharedPreferences() {
        val sharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences(myPreferences, Context.MODE_PRIVATE)
        val editor = sharedPreferences.edit()
        editor.putString("Selected Value",radioButtonValue)
        editor.apply()
    }
```

In the Second login time, I've used the below method to get the value from shared preferences that was already set at the first login time.

```
fun getSharedPreferences(): String {
         val prefs = getSharedPreferences(myPreferences, Context.MODE_PRIVATE)
         restoredValue= prefs.getString("text", devMode)
         return restoredValue
}
```

This the code that I've used to change the color of toolbar in the second login time

```
 val restoredText=getSharedPreferences()
 if(restoredText==="selectedRadioButtonValue")
 {
   toolbar.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#FF0000"));
 }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

first of all in your `getSharedPreferences` method you try to receive different key value than you set on the first login (you are saving first login state in `Selected Value` key and try to receive from different key which is `text`)

second for your answer try below code

```
val restoredText=getSharedPreferences()
 if(restoredText.equals("selectedRadioButtonValue"))
 {
   toolbar.setBackgroundDrawable(ColorDrawable(Color.parseColor("#YOUR_COLOR_CODE")))
 }
}
```

Comment: Ok,I'll try that and I've used the following lines of code for logout functionality but it is not working ```val next = Intent(this@LogoutActivity, LoginActivity::class.java)
                startActivity(next)
                next.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
                this.finish()```

Comment: use this code snip `next.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP)` before calling `startActivity(next) `

Comment: I've used that and I'm able to get the value which is stored in sharedpreferences as suggested by you but even after that the toolbar color is not changing

Comment: check that whether change background code snip is running or not

Comment: the way that I'm using is correct or not for logout as well as for condition??

Comment: just use log or debugger to check whether your condition code snip is invoke or not or add your login activity full code here so i can check where actual problem is

Comment: Following is code that I've used to change the color. I've used log as well and both are not working.I'll add `onCreate` method here ```override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?){ super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
setContentView(R.layout.activity_launcher)
setSupportActionBar(toolbar)
val envSwitchInfo=getSharedPreferences() Log.d("Selected environment",""+envSwitchInfo)
        if(envSwitchInfo==="Production") {
 toolbar.setBackgroundDrawable( ColorDrawable(Color.parseColor("#FF0000")))
            Log.d("Value is",""+envSwitchInfo)
        } ```

Comment: It is working fine .Now I'm able to change the toolbar color :) `if(envSwitchInfo==="Production")` instead of this, I've used `if(envSwitchInfo.equals("Production"))`